# add on click event for the button

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to add the `click` event to the button. I keep the button in the row of the table in the `td` tag. I do like this

```
var btn_td = document.createElement('td');
var button = document.createElement('button');
button.innerHTML = 'delete';
button.onclick = function() {
    alert('attempt to delete' + books[j].id);
    removeFileById(books[j].id);
}

btn_td.appendChild(button);
tr.appendChild(btn_td);
```

But when I click on `button` - nothing happens. No `alert`, no request to the page`.

Button is added to the table just fine

[image]

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. All sorts of things are missing here. There's no HTML. There's no `j`. There's no report as to what the Developer Tools Console shows (are there errors? Are there explicitly no errors?)

Comment: The code you provided works fine after removing non-defined expressions such as `books[j]` and `removeFileById(books[j].id)`, so you might want to have a look at those. Can you provide a snippet or a fiddle? HTML code?

Comment: yay, indeed. it was not able to find `books[j].id`. As soon as I set it to the variable before `onclick` definition and provided it to the function, it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: It's good practice to use addEventListener rather than directly accessing the click properties.

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('attempt to delete' + books[j].id);
  removeFileById(books[j].id);
});
```

Don't forget that it's good practice to remove the event listener when the element no longer exists / is being used. So if you have any functions that delete the `button` element, then you should call `button.removeEventListener`.

Comment: I'm afraid that you're not quiet get the problem. Code provided by user is work as expected. onclick will work. He just has another error (I guess something like 'books undefined')

Comment: There's no need to use an `addEventListener`, although it may be a good practice, original poster code works fine when removing non-defined expression such as `books`

Comment: Ah good point! I merely assumed the poster had double checked all available variables :)

Answer (score 0):

```
document. getElementsByTagName("button").addEventListener("click", function(){
    alert('attempt to delete' + books[j].id);
removeFileById(books[j].id);
});
```

Comment: **From review queue:** May I request you to please add some context around your source-code. Code-only answers are difficult to understand.
It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not (want to) use jQuery, you should use **addEventListener()** method on your element, like this :

```
button.addEventListener('click', function() { 
    // Doing what you want ... 
});
```

Good continuation :)